# C++ [class] was not declared in this scope while using shared library

Tags: c++

I've created a shared library project that does various things with a couple of different classes that I wrote.  So my question is more clear, please note the header file below:

TsmClient.h

```
#include "Headers/Framework/BoostSocket.h"
#include "DataContracts.h"

#ifndef TSMCLIENT_H_
#define TSMCLIENT_H_

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::asio;

class TsmClient {
public:
    TsmClient();
    TsmClient(std::string host);
    virtual ~TsmClient();

    bool IsConnected();

    friend class WarehouseFramework;

private:
    std::string Communicate(std::string &req);

    std::string serverHost;
    int port;
    std::shared_ptr<BoostSocket> socket;
    io_service service;

    void Connect();
    void Close();
};
```

By itself, this project builds just fine and produces a .so file.  However, when I attempt to use this library in another project, I am having issues accessing a class that I have written in DataContracts.h.  The exact error is:

> WarehouseSettingTemplateList’ was not declared in this scope

I am able to create an instance of TsmClient and call functions successfully all day long, and since TsmClient.h includes DataContracts.h, I'm a little confused as to why I can't use a class that is declared in DataContracts.h.  Does this have to do with the fact that I'm compiling this project as a shared library?

Here is DataContracts.h

```
    #include "Headers/Framework/Proto/TcpFramework.pb.h"
    #include "Headers/Framework/Proto/ProductManagement.pb.h"
    #include "Headers/Framework/Proto/KioskManagement.pb.h"
    #include "Headers/Framework/Proto/WarehouseManagement.pb.h"
    #include "Headers/Framework/Proto/CashTillManagement.pb.h"
    #include "Headers/Framework/Proto/AccountManagement.pb.h"
    #include "Headers/Framework/Proto/VendorManagement.pb.h"
    #include "Headers/Framework/Proto/ShoppingCartManagement.pb.h"
    #include "Headers/Framework/Proto/Generic.pb.h"
    #include "Headers/Framework/Proto/OfflineManagement.pb.h"
    #include "Headers/Framework/Proto/CouponManagement.pb.h"
    #include "Headers/Utils/Utilities.h"

    using namespace StokedProtoBuf;

    #ifndef DATACONTRACTS_H_
    #define DATACONTRACTS_H_

class WarehouseSettingTemplate {
public:
    long idWarehouse;
    int idWarehouseSettingType;
    std::string Value;
    bool IsEnabled;

    std::string Serialize();
    void Deserialize(const std::string &data);
private:
    WarehouseSettingTemplate_Proto proto;
};

class WarehouseSettingTemplateList {
public:
    std::vector<WarehouseSettingTemplate> settingList;
    std::string Serialize();
    void Deserialize(const std::string &data);
private:
    WarehouseSettingTemplateList_Proto proto;
};
```

I'm sure this is a stupid oversight on my part but it is driving me insane.

Comment: Placing `using namespace` statements in header files is just asking for trouble.

Comment: so, how does the file that actually reports the error looks like?

Comment: @pqnet, I don't quite understand what you are asking.  The error is coming from G++ when I compile the project that is using this shared library.

Comment: which file is the one pointed out by the error `WarehouseSettingTemplateList’ was not declared in this scope`?

Comment: also, `DataContracts.h` lacks a `#endif` statement at the end. Is it ok?

Comment: @tier1 May be non related, but nevertheless: Place the include guards from the very beginning of the header (surround the `#include` statements also).

Comment: wait, did you `#include "DataContracts.h"` in the file using `WarehouseSettingTemplateList` in your other project?

Comment: @pqnet, the file actually throwing the error is in a separate project all together.  As far as the #endif, I just forgot to add it in the code chunk

Comment: @pqnet, Originally I did not, thinking that it was included by TsmClient.h so why would I need to?  However, I did try it after it did not work initially but still no success.

Comment: @tier1 the file actually throwing the error has some wrong in it, there is nothing wrong with the code you showed here (except for bad design), so the error should be somewhere else. About `#include "DataContracts.h"`, if you include `TsmClient.h` it should be the same thing

Comment: @pqnet  I would post it but it has 2k lines of code in it.  I'll take a closer look at that file and post back shortly.

Comment: @tier1 maybe try to post the header part in which you include files and use `#ifdefs` in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) or similar. There should be some trouble with macros which prevent `DataContracts.h` being included

Comment: @tier1 I think we can agree, that it's not really a problem specific for shared libraries, since it occurs pre-linking stage, right?

Comment: Try using the -save-temps option to gcc.  It will produce an intermediate preprocessed .i file.  Once you have this, you can locate the line where you first use WarehouseSettingTemplateList, then look and see if the declaration is *above* that use point.  It might not be (inclusion issue), or it might be in another namespace, or it might be misspelled.  Either way you'll have more to go on.

Comment: And by the way, come prepared with grep because the .i file will be massive.

Comment: @pqnet I removed the #ifndef DATACONTRACTS_H_ lines and it seems to work now.  I have no idea why

Comment: maybe you had same macro defined somewhere else in your include chain. Try to look for files which contains `DATACONTRACTS_H` string. You should have include guards, if you remove them completely you're going to face a lot of problems in the near future. Maybe you can try to change the name.

Comment: @pqnet very possible.  I agree with having guards so I might monkey around with it for awhile further to try to get them to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question after all of the help that I've received, but here is what was wrong...

I had a header file in my shared library called DataContracts.h.  In my main project, I also had a header file called DataContracts.h

So I think that my include guards where preventing the shared library header file to be imported.  This is the first time that I've really worked with shared libraries before so I hope that this will help other people if they run into this issue.

--I feel bad because I did not provide enough information for anybody else to answer this question.

Comment: *facepalm* Same here. I really hate it when I copy headers that I can reuse (but the difference is too great to inherit from the classes they include) and forget to change the guards. I wish IDEs were capable of telling the developer that he/she has forgotten to take care of that or maybe even automatically rename the guard (if name of file has also been changed).

Answer (score 0):

First its better that you have your header guard (#ifndef/#define) on the top of your file (above your includes)

Second, make sure that every class is available in your .so and the program you linking against.

Third, You should not use inline declarations in your classes which will be exported otherwise at compile time the linker cannot choose which definition to use (the definition in your .so file or your program).

Comment: As for your second point: The OP's error is certainly not related to linking.

Comment: First suggestion is good. Second is not pertinent : it is a compile error, not a link error so the .so files are not yet checked. Third, it is ok to put inline declaration in classes, as long as they are inside the braces of the class declaration, still it would again be an error at link time

Comment: Oops I simply overseen that. Ok, make sure that you don't use a using namespace directive in your header files and make sure your headers have a proper header guard because your headers lack of an #endif at the bottom